# Unable to get records using a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm making a web application where users can create playlists and add musics (like Spotify, Deezer, etc.). But I can't manage to get musics in a playlist. Over here are my Playlist and Music classes:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Melodie.Models
{
    public class Playlist
    {
        [Key, Column("playlist_id")]
        public int? PlaylistId { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("user_id")]
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("color_id")]
        public int? ColorId { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("name"), MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText), Column("Description"), MaxLength(255)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        
        public List<Music> Musics { get; set; }

        public Playlist()
        {
            UserId = 1;
            ColorId = 1;
            Name = "Nouvelle playlist";
            //Musics = new List<Music>();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Melodie.Models
{
    public class Music
    {
        [Key, Column("music_id")]
        public int? MusicId { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("playlist_id")]
        public int? PlaylistId { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("playlist_id")]
        //public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
        public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("name"), MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        
        [Required, Column("file_path"), MaxLength(2048)]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        
        
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile MusicFile { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

I tried to follow many guides, including [this one by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) but I can't get all musics that have the same `PlaylistId` when loading the display page. I retrieve my playlist data using this function:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Playlist>> GetPlaylistsOf(int userId)
{
    return await _db.Playlists
        .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
        .Include(p => p.Musics)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.PlaylistId)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one was pretty foolish.

When I saw the answers of Qudus and Svyatoslav Danyliv, I realized that all this time I was editing the function `GetPlaylistsOf(int userId)` instead of `GetPlaylistById(int playlistId)` which are completly differrent. So this is now working perfectly:

```cs
public async Task<Playlist> GetPlaylistById(int playlistId)
{
    return await _db.Playlists
        .Include(p => p.Musics)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PlaylistId == playlistId);
}
        
public async Task<IEnumerable<Playlist>> GetPlaylistsOf(int userId)
{
    return await _db.Playlists
        .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.PlaylistId)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

`List<Musics>` collection is not actually directly stored in your database. Rather query for all music in a playlist by their `playlistId` and `userId`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Music>> GetPlaylistsOf(int userId, int playlistId)
{
    return await _db.Musics
        .Include(p => p.Playlist)
        .Where(p => p.Playlist.UserId == userId)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.PlaylistId)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need this one:

```cs
public Task<IEnumerable<Music>> GetUserMusic(int userId)
{
    return _db.Playlists
        .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
        .SelectMany(p => p.Musics)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```